# Figure out the element in the a table (using class) when using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using a table grid in my HTML and while clicking on a specific `col` in each row, I dynamically create an additional row using `<tr>`. The additional row is used to submit data to the server and remove it after submit. Now I would like in addition to this that the row number of the table will be sent to the server as well.

The table is changed dynamically as I am adding rows for editing. I thought about fixing this by giving each `<tr>` a class named `task_entry` and by counting the number of `.task_entry` elements I will be able to figure out which row I am in. However I cannot get this to work. I tried to use `$(".task_entry").index(this)` but it returns -1.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you're adding rows dinamically then it won't be picked up by javascript. In this case you need to use [jQuery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use .live() as it's deprecated.

Please try playing this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mB49c/1/

Based on the structure in it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('table').on('click', 'td', function() {

        //count the row. 0 based. If you want to start at 1, add 1
        var my_row = $(this).parent('tr').index('table tr');

        $('table').append('<tr class="saving"><td>Col 1</td><td>Col 2</td><td>Col 3</td><td>Col 4</td><td>Col 5</td></tr>');


        alert('You clicked on row ' + my_row + ' run some code.. for instance AJAX');

        //If using AJAX, add this as a Success callback
        $('.saving').remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $("table td").click(function() {
    var this_is = $(this).attr("id");
    var this_val = $(this).html();

    alert(this_val)

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check what `this` is in your case. Could it be the col, you are clicking on? Then `$(".task_entry").index($(this).closest('tr'))` should do the trick.